# Is it possible to convert a before_destroy to an inline function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to convert this to an inline function?

```
before_destroy :no_accounts_check, prepend: true

def no_accounts_check
  throw(:abort) unless accounts.count.zero?
end
```

I tried doing this

```
before_destroy { throw(:abort) unless accounts.count.zero? }, prepend: true
```

but it's giving me a syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting `end')
... unless accounts.count.zero? }, prepend: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work...

```
before_destroy prepend: true do
  throw(:abort) unless accounts.count.zero?
end
```